# What's the difference between tabindex="false" and empty tabindex?

Tags: html, focus, accessibility, tabindex

As per the title, what is the difference when I have `tabIndex="false"` versus having empty `tabIndex`? As a bonus, what's the difference with having `tabIndex="false"` versus `tabIndex=false` versus empty `tabIndex`?

For example: 
`<a tabIndex="false" />` versus `<a tabIndex />` versus `<a tabIndex=false />`

I haven't been able to find any resource or stackoverflow question that sheds light on this scenario.

Thanks in advance~

Comment: `tabindex` can only have integers as values. `false` doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @Xufox so for all of the cases above, tabIndex is evaluating to `undefined`, or `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.

As [Xufox explains in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319590/whats-the-difference-between-tabindex-false-and-empty-tabindex#comment81590386_47319590), `tabindex` can only have integers as values. This is indicated in the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-tabindex):

> The tabindex attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a valid integer.

Having `tabindex` (without a value), or `tabindex="false"` or `tabindex=false` is irrelevant as all of them will fail the [rules for parsing integers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#rules-for-parsing-integers) (in steps 5, 7, and 7 respectively). In those cases, browsers will ignore the value and apply the logic that they apply by default to any element.

So all of the following would be treated equally:

```
<input tabindex="false" />
<input tabindex=false />
<input tabindex="" />
<input tabindex />
<input />
```

Comment: ahh I see. Thank you for the concise answer